# update device with settings from cloud

Tags: push-notification, embedded, cloud, settings, device

I have a device which has a settings on it.
The device is uploading data to the cloud.
In the cloud I have settings of the device that I want to do a smart way to update the device settings, but still leave the device the master and stateless. I mean that every request shall come from the device towards the cloud and NACK/ACK will come back to the device.

Currently what we do is to put a command in the database to send to the device according to its serial number. when the device pings to the server, it gets the message with the update. But I do not want to wait for the ping of the BSS. How can I notify the device that a message is waiting for it ?
How do Apple does it with icloud settings to the devices ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the MQTT protocol.  This is being promoted by Amazon for IOT devices, and a broker (message router) is available from Amazon.  The protocol uses a publish and subscriber model.  The devices subscribe to their "topic" something like yourcompany/todevice/serialnumber, and when the server publishes to the same topic, the MQTT broker delivers the message.  the messages normally use JSON protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much